# httpdocs / public html permission issue

Tags: error, permissions, apache

I was trying to install an extension to our magento store using 'Magento Downloader' but I got the following error message:

> Your Magento folder does not have sufficient write permissions, which downloader requires.

As I was browsing the web for a solution one of them was to temporary set your httpdocs or 'public html' folder to '777' however upon doing this, it has now taken our website offline <del>which you can see here:</del> giving a "503 Service Unavailable" error and showing a Magento error page:

> **Service Temporarily Unavailable**
>   The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

How can I fix this? I tried setting the permissions back to the original ones but the same page still displays with "Service Temporarily Unavailable".

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at this page of the Magento documentation which gives a good summary on how permissions should be set on a Magento install: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html

Comment: Up Vote follow them docs